# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:snowflake

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've installed all the necessary packages:

```
pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

I am running this test code from the snowflake docs:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(
    'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/'.format(
        user='<your_user_login_name>',
        password='<your_password>',
        account='<your_account_name>',
    )
)
try:
    connection = engine.connect()
    results = connection.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()
    print(results[0])
finally:
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

My output should be the snowflake version e.g. 1.48.0

But I get the error

> NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:snowflake

(I am trying to run this in Anaconda)

Comment: I faced the same problem too. But after I upgraded `snowflake-sqlalchemy` using the command line you wrote above, the connection was successful.

Comment: facing the same error message and no solution yet even after I upgraded `snowflake-sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 15):

I had similar issues when I tried to deploy code to an Azure Function App. `sqlalchemy` would find the module when I ran the code locally, but it failed to resolve the dialect on remote deployment and execution.

I resolved the issue there by running the following before calling `create_engine`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry

...

registry.register('snowflake', 'snowflake.sqlalchemy', 'dialect')
```

I suspect that `snowflake-sqlalchemy` fails to self-register in certain environments.

Comment: Mine is the opposite. Works in my azure function (docker container) but not locally (outside of the docker container)

Answer (score 5):

This error generally appears due to a bad installation of the sqlalchemy package. Check the `sqlalchemy.dialects` folder to ensure that your dbapi folder exists.

Try to upgrade your sqlalchemy package:

```
pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy
```

Answer (score 5):

`pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy` worked for me

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#installing-snowflake-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a couple additional imports:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was deploying through serverless using pythonRequirements and has the same issue.

I removed the slim option and it worked, but I don't like it because it makes the zip file for my amazon lambda bigger.
I just want to let others know there might be something wrong with the slim option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using conda? Then

```
conda install --yes snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

Note, it also still requires `snowflake-connector-python` being installed as well!

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - snowflake-sqlalchemy

Comment: All needed to do was to install snowflake-sqlalchemy. In my case used pip asI am not using conda. pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy. You may need to uninstalled.