# Pyinstaller, hidden imports not included

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I read every manual and answers here, but still don't understand Pyinstaller's behavior.

I'd edited a .spec file where added my imports:

```
hiddenimports=['ftfy','sqlalchemy','mysql','pymysql','xlrd','xlwt','xlutils']
```

All of these packages were installed with `pip`.

Some interesting issues while Pyinstaller builds one-folder:

```
62573 INFO:   Found 4 sqlalchemy hidden imports
62577 WARNING: Hidden import "pysqlite2" not found!
62580 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
67597 WARNING: Hidden import "sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func" not found!
67623 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'sqlalchemy.testing'
```

`sqlalchemy` really uses other packages, in my project it's a `mysql` for connecting to MySQL DB. Every lib is in the default directory `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages`

1. Why after `dist` is made I see nothing from my `hiddenimport`? 
   Seems like statement doesn't really work. When I try run .exe:

   ```
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\rs_al\\IdeaProjects\\ExcelToSQL\\PyXLSQL\\dist\\service\\ftfy\\char_classes.dat'

   [1668] Failed to execute script service
   ```
2. Shall I totally trust to  `pyinstaller` analyzed dependencies? I use a small part of `pandas` and `pyinstaller` suggests to hook a `numpy`package.

Comment: This seems related to the fact that the library you are using is not bundling the .dat file because is not a python file. What you need is a custom hook to include this data in your final executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue related to snowflake is common - be it NoModuleFound Error while executing the .exe file, or be it a Hidden import error during compilation.

Include the following 3 imports. It worked for me.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
```

Please refer to this Stackoverflow page for more solutions: [NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284762/nosuchmoduleerror-cant-load-plugin-sqlalchemy-dialectssnowflake)